# Reading a binary file from Google Drive using node.js

Tags: javascript, binary, google-drive-api

I'm running into a problem getting a binary from Drive using the API, I keep going in circles.

Here are the relevant code bits:

```
// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Drive API.
  oauth.authorize(JSON.parse(content), dasm.init, driveapi.getFile)
});
```

driveapi.getFile:

```
function getFile(auth, cb) {
  var service = google.drive('v3');
  service.files.get({
    auth: auth,
    pageSize: 20,
    fileId: "0B2h-dgPh8_5CZE9WZVM4a3BxV00",
    alt: 'media'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    cb(response)
  });
}
```

Now, `response` appears to be coming back as a string. When I try to convert to hex it goes nuts. Is there any way to to take `response` and get it into a `Buffer`? Or is it corrupted the sec I get it from `service.files.get` ?

By nuts, I mean that

```
console.log(
        arrData[0].charCodeAt(0).toString(2),
        '-',
        arrData[1].charCodeAt(0).toString(2),
        '-',
        arrData[2].charCodeAt(0).toString(2),
        '-',
        arrData[3].charCodeAt(0).toString(2),
        '-',
        arrData[4].charCodeAt(0).toString(2)
    )
```

= 1001101 - 1011010 - 1111111111111101 - 0 - 11 (I'm using binary to try to see what is broken)

The correct hex would be 4D 5A 90 00 03

Edit: For those who are confused, like I was, how `90` became `fffd` it's the [Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) that gets displayed when the value doesn't map to an ASCII char.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was able to solve this, finally. Google APIs use the request module, and you can [apply any options](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#options) that it accepts. For reference, you will need to set `[encoding: null]`[2](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback), as any other option will pass the response though toString, thus ruining it if you are working with binary data.

Working code is located below:

```
function getFile(auth, cb) {
  var service = google.drive({
    version: 'v3', 
    encoding: null
  });
  service.files.get({
    auth: auth,
    fileId: "0B2h-dgPh8_5CZE9WZVM4a3BxV00",
    alt: 'media'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    cb(response)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on an article in [MDN about sending and receiving binary data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)

```
function getFile(auth, cb) {
  var service = google.drive('v3');
  service.files.get({
  auth: auth,
  pageSize: 20,
  fileId: "0B2h-dgPh8_5CZE9WZVM4a3BxV00",
  alt: 'media'
 }, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  var arrayBuffer = response; 
  if (arrayBuffer) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
      // do something with each byte in the array
    }
  }
 }
```

If you do not get a byte array your will have to convert the string to a bytearray with the code below.

```
var bytes = [];
for (var i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; ++i) {
  bytes.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
}
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(bytes);
for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
   // do something with each byte in the array
}
```

Comment: This example only seems to work when setting `responseType = "arraybuffer"`, something I do not appear to be able to do with Drive API. Your code example returns a generic object of zero length.