# File coming back as string

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

When trying to download a file using javascript and the google file api referenced here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files

The response body has been encoded as text. The problem is downloading binary files (.sav) which then become encoded incorrectly. The code I'm using is straight forward:

```
gapi.client.drive.files.get({ 'fileId': self.selectedFileId, alt: 'media' }).then((response) => {
 // response.body is text
}
```

According to [Reading a binary file from Google Drive using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826608/reading-a-binary-file-from-google-drive-using-node-js) You can set encoding null but I can't see that anywhere in the current (v3) REST api.

Comment: Which scopes are you using? Do you have full read access to the file? (not metadata read access)

Comment: scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' and yes I have full access to the file. The file contents are set back but they are encoded as a string

Comment: @Jescanellas Not sure if this helps ?

Answer (score 4):

OK so I figured out what I was doing wrong I was converting the string straight into a blob to pass on to my backend I needed to convert to a typed array before converting to a blob:

```
      gapi.client.drive.files.get({ 'fileId': self.selectedFileId, alt: 'media' }).then((response) => {

          const charArray = new Array(response.body.length);
          for (let i = 0; i < response.body.length; i++) {
              charArray[i] = response.body.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          const typedArray = new Uint8Array(charArray);

          const blob = new Blob([typedArray], {type: response.headers['Content-Type']});
```

Hopefull this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

I was having exactly the same issue, had a jpeg file on Drive and it was returning a string: `"ÿØÿà\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000`

looking at the response headers:

```
"headers": {
"cache-control": "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
"content-encoding": "gzip",
"content-type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
"date": "Wed, 24 Feb 2021 20:57:27 GMT",
"expires": "Wed, 24 Feb 2021 20:57:27 GMT",
"server": "UploadServer",
"vary": "Origin, X-Origin",
"x-guploader-uploadid": "ABg5-Uxki1DGxu2guatOLHR3Ixp4HRPxPUvGVk0omTun3qGM_89kO4jYQl9OWhEBpQZW1gUphzmr1mdBtzgKUiOdUgabVBo30A",
"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
```

},

you'll see there are two content type headers.... one of which is

```
"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
```

I suspect this is a bug ! After all if I'm requesting the file as binary by using "alt: 'media'" I expect binary not mangled binary as text!

Thanks to @Dave3of5 it now works!